# Conditional scoring

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that shows only the 'captured' data. For example in the below exhibit, the emp_no 17 has 2 records - for November and February (for a specified 6 month period, from July 2017). It does not have data for the other 4 months (within the 6-month date range, from previous 6 months to current date).

How can I populate these missing months (Sept, Oct, Dec) with default values for num_differences of 0 for the missing months?  (for example, in this case, I want emp_no 17 to have the below (I can ignore 2018 data - only require data up to Dec 2017):

I have the script below:

```
declare @YMN date;
set @YMN = '20171201';

DECLARE @Emp TABLE (

[date] date,

[emp_no] int,
[num_differences] int
);

INSERT INTO @Emp VALUES
('2017-09-14', 17, 1), ('2017-12-01', 17, 1),('2017-12-18', 17, 1),('2017-12-21', 17, 1),

('2017-09-27', 17, 1), ('2017-12-04', 17, 1);

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------get missing dates---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ;WITH cte_Emp_No AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT [emp_no]
    FROM @Emp
    ),
    cte_dates AS (
    SELECT [emp_no], DATEADD(month, -6, DATEADD(dd, -(DAY(dateadd(month, 1, @YMN)) - 1), dateadd(month, 1, @YMN))) AS [date]
    FROM cte_Emp_No
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [emp_no], DATEADD(month, 1, [date]) AS [date]
    FROM cte_dates
    WHERE [date] < dateadd(month, 0, @YMN)
    )

    SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(e.emp_no, c.emp_no) emp_no, ISNULL(e.date, c.date) date, ISNULL(e.num_differences, 0) num_differences 
    into ##new_table 
    FROM @Emp AS e
    RIGHT JOIN cte_dates AS c ON YEAR(c.date) = YEAR(e.date) AND MONTH(c.date) = MONTH(e.date)

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------MAIN CTE------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;with cte_RawScore as
    (
    select emp_no
       , date YMN
       ,sum(case when datediff(month, convert(datetime, @YMN, 112), date) = 0 then num_differences else 0 end) as thismonth
       ,sum(case when datediff(month, convert(datetime, @YMN, 112), date) between -2 and 0 then num_differences else 0 end) as last3month
       ,sum(case when datediff(month, convert(datetime, @YMN, 112), date) between -5 and 0 then num_differences else 0 end) as last6month
    from ##new_table d
    group by emp_no, date
    )

    select 
       emp_no
       ,YMN
       ,case when last6month  = 0 then 5
     when last3month  = 0 then 4
     when thismonth  = 0 then 3
     when thismonth  <= 3 then 2
    else 1 end RawScore
    from cte_RawScore 
    ORDER BY day(YMN) desc

    drop table ##new_table
```

I want this the scoring only to be applicable for 6 months from and after July 2017. i.e. the @YMN is a variable that stores the year month number; and the score, according to the above rule applies to the 6 months from 201707.

So 201707 is 1 month,

201708 is 2 months, etc, up to 201712

I wish to have a list of employees with their associated scores, based on the rules mentioned below .

That’s, :

A score of 5 if 0 differences in 6 consecutive months ( from July to December) ;

A score of 4 if 0 differences in 3 consecutive months (from July to December);

A score of 3 if 0 differences for 1 month ( from July to December);

A score of 2 if 1 to 3 differences for 1 month (from July to December);

A score of 1 if 4 or more differences in 1 month (from July to December).

I get the number of differences from a table, but some employees do not appear for certain months; hence I want to give them a difference of 0 if they do not appear for that particular month.

Please assist.

Comment: I don't understand your question. I think you should proof-read it yourself because I am sure you have made some mistake while explaining it. Plus you should keep your question as short as possible.

Comment: I have data like the below

Comment: @Ziii You have written an explanation as answer. add it to the question by editing the question. and delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're getting at. Let me give you a simplified example. You need a table full of dates to join to. In data warehousing we use a Date dimension which has attributes about every date.

For your example your date dimension table could just have Month names or numbers:

1
2
...
12

Let's call this table Months.

Then you would do something like this, to count a zero for months with no data. Here I'm using what's called a Common Table Expression or CTE (the part with the WITH) in place of a table, since I'm not concerned with creating a permanent table right now.

```
WITH Months AS (
    SELECT 1 AS MonthNumber UNION
    SELECT 2 UNION
    SELECT 3 UNION
    SELECT 4 UNION
    SELECT 5 UNION
    SELECT 6 UNION
    SELECT 7 UNION
    SELECT 8 UNION
    SELECT 9 UNION
    SELECT 10 UNION
    SELECT 11 UNION
    SELECT 12         
)
SELECT M.MonthNumber, COUNT(*)
FROM Months as M 
    LEFT JOIN MyData as D 
        ON MONTH(D.SomeDateValue) = M.MonthNumber
GROUP BY M.MonthNumber
```

This will guarantee every month appears with a count, perhaps of zero.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but I currently do not work in a DW environment. Please assist, Thanks

Comment: Can you add a table with all months. That is what that answer is suggesting you do

Comment: If you're allowed to add a simple table. For my example above, you could do: CREATE TABLE Months ( MonthNumber int ); INSERT INTO Months (MonthNumber) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12); If you're only allowed to create temporary tables, you can add a pound sign to the front of the Months table name, like #Months. These temporary tables are dropped when you log out.